# Why points were not imported from Excel file into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, import, excel, utm

I have a data of multiple x and y coordinates in UTM format saved in an Excel CSV file format then added it as a delimited text layer in QGIS. I set the geometry definition as "point coordinates" but when I added it, there are no points that appears on the map. How do I make QGIS to plot my coordinates to the map. I already set up the geometry CRS to UTM Zone 51N.

Comment: Well, have you told QGIS which columns hold the x- and y-coordinates while importing the data?

Answer (score 3):

See screenshot. Just follow the indications in the screenshot.
[image]